# JSON Schema take values from another file (non-json), take file names

Tags: json, yaml, jsonschema

Is it possible to restrict values, or property names in the schema in accordance with data defined in another json (non-schema, just data file) file? Or even take files from a folder and process their names?

For example, YAML:
file 1:

```
Attributes:
 - Attribute1
 - Attribute2
```

file2:

```
Influence:
 Attribute1: 1
 Attribute2: -3
```

**I want to have syntax help in the second file that depends on the data defined in the first file.** How can I do it?

### And harder case

there is a folder with some YAMLs/JSONs describe some events.
like:
Events/event1.yaml
Events/subfolder/event2.yaml

Another file should use only file names defined in the folder
For example:

```
DefaultEvents:
 - event1
 - event2
```

Is it possible and how to get autocomplete with JSON Schema in such a case?

It's not about validation, I need syntax help, autocomplete during making such files.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: YAML as markup language

Comment: https://json-schema-everywhere.github.io/yaml might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility I found is to add all possible values to JsonSchema dynamically with any programming language you use.
This solution will be sufficient when JsonSchema is stored locally in your project.